# Stop PHPUnit's DBUnit from inserting XML dataset in database

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, phpunit

Is there a way to stop DBUnit from creating a record based on an XML dataset?

I'm trying to test if a query will insert a record then compare it to the XML dataset.

```
public function testInsert()
{
    $statement = $this->getConnection()
        ->getConnection()
        ->query(
        'insert into Grades (Vendor) values (\'test\')'
    );

    $actual = $this->getConnection()->createQueryTable(
        'Grades',
        'select Vendor from Grades'
    );

    $this->assertTablesEqual(
        $this->getDataSet()->getTable('Grades'),
        $actual
    );
}

public function getDataset()
{
    //returns dataset below
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataset>
    <Grades
        uid="345"
    />
</dataset>
```

The result is:

```
PHPUnit: Failed asserting that 

+----------------------+
| Grades               |
+----------------------+
|        Vendor        |
+----------------------+
|         test         |
+----------------------+
|         test         |
+----------------------+

 is equal to expected 
+----------------------+
| Grades               |
+----------------------+
|        Vendor        |
+----------------------+
|         test         |
+----------------------+
```

Can someone explain why the XML Dataset is inserted at all and how I can stop it from doing so automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I'm supposed to use an empty "base" table XML before comparing results.

```
public function getDataSet()
{
    return $this->createFlatXMLDataSet("seed.xml");
}

public function testUpdate()
{
    $statement = $this->getConnection()
        ->getConnection()
        ->query(
        'insert into Grades (Vendor) values (\'test\')'
    );

    $actual = new \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_QueryDataSet($this->getConnection());

    $actual->addTable(
        'Grades',
        'select Vendor from Grades'
    );

    $expected = $this->createFlatXMLDataSet("expected.xml");

    $this->assertDataSetsEqual(
        $expected,
        $actual
    );
}
```

**seed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataset>
    <Grades
    />
</dataset>
```

**expected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataset>
    <Grades
        Vendor="test"
    />
</dataset>
```